# mat-card and its contents varies in size if I do inspect element

Tags: html, css, angular, frontend

I am new in angular framework(or rather in front end itself). I have developed a log in page using angular material. While working on it I opened the inspect element and I noticed that the size of mat-card is shrinking and because of that mat-card-title is also changing its place from the original place. Also when I clicked on 'toggle device toolbar' the entire mat-card and its containing elements changes their place drastically. I am attaching the relevant snapshots and code.

1)Normal View.
[image: Normal View]

2)Inspect element without enabling toggle device toolbar.
[image: Inspect element without enabling toggle device toolbar]

3)After Enabling Toggle Device option from inspect element.
[image: After Enabling Toggle Device option from inspect element]

I am expecting that when I am doing inspect element or toggle device toolbar, the mat-card and its contents should be as it is as we can see in the normal view image.(I mean they should adjust according to the size of the screen).

loginpage.component.html

```
<!-- <div class="center"> -->
    <mat-card class="box">
            <mat-card-title>User Login</mat-card-title>
            <form [formGroup] = "login">
                <mat-card-content>
                    <mat-label>Username</mat-label>
                        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width-padding" floatLabel="auto" appearance="fill" color="warn">
                            <input matInput #username name="usename" placeholder="username" type="text" formControlName="username" required>
                        </mat-form-field>
                        
                        <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
                        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" floatLabel="auto" appearance="fill" color="warn">
                            <input matInput #password name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" formControlName="password" required>
                        </mat-form-field>
                        <div class="login-error" *ngIf="!isSuccess">
                            <mat-icon>report_problem</mat-icon>Your Username and/or Password are incorrect.
                        </div>
                </mat-card-content>
            </form>
        <mat-card-actions>
            <button (click) = "LoginUser(username,password)" type = "submit" class="button-class-left" mat-raised-button color="warn" [disabled]="!login.valid">LogIn</button>
            <button routerLink="/SignUp" type="submit" class="button-class-left" mat-raised-button color="warn">SignUp</button>
        </mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card>
<!-- </div> -->
```

loginpage.component.css

```
.example-full-width-padding{
    width:  100%;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.example-full-width{
    width:  100%;
}

mat-label{
    position: relative;
    width:  100%;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: black;
    padding: 5px;
}

.example-form {
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
    width: 100%;
}

.box{
    position: relative;
    width: 25%;
    margin-left: 38%;
    margin-top: 13%;
    /* box-shadow: 5px 10px red; */
}
mat-card-title{
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 160px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.button-class-left{
    position: relative;
    width: 20%;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.login-error{
    font-size: 16px;
    color: red;
}
```

[image: Project Folder Structure]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do not give width to .box in %age. Do let me know if it helps

Comment: I tried to give width in cm but that is not working.
This is what I did.
box{
    position: relative;
    width:30cm;
    margin-left: 38%;
    margin-top: 13%;
    /* box-shadow: 5px 10px red; */
}